# Is "farth" a word in any language?

Tags: meaning

Due to a misreading, a group including myself have searched for the definition of the word "farth" and come up with nothing.  We now know that the original text did not actually use this word, but the word still strikes us as feeling eerily familiar and somehow fitting of the context in which is was found - a geographic feature found in uncivilized wilderness.

The original quote (we thought we read) was:

> North past forest, farth, and furrow
>
> You must go to reach the feathered mound

We later found out that the word that was meant to be there was **farm**.  Nonetheless, we have found a fascination with this potentially made-up word.

Is "farth" actually a word in any version of English, Latin, or other Roman-character-using languages?

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries?

Comment: Indeed.  I've done a decent amount of Google searching through online dictionaries, and have found no matches at all.

Comment: Would you mind giving us the sentence where this word appears? Depending on the context, it might well end up being an obvious misprint for _farthing_, as starwed suggests.

Comment: Urban Dictionary has a suggestion. It is just a silly joke, though.

Comment: I look and look at this word, and all I see is 'fart'

Comment: In French, "farth" sounds awfully close to "farce" (_joke_). However, no _pure_ Latin language (Latin, Italian, Spanish, French) has the "th" sound.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* says it was once used in English:

> **farth**: *alleged synonym of* farrow n. 2.
>
> 1688 R. Holme *Armoury* ii. 134/1: "The young ones...of a sow...are called a Farth, a Farrow of Pigs."

So a *farrow* is the/an act of giving birth to a nest of piglets.

Comment: This is, ironically, very related to the actual word, "farm", that we misread.  Amusing!

Answer (score 7):

Very few languages have *th* sounds, much less following another consonant at the end of a word. However, there is apparently such a word in Icelandic. A post on [this page](http://www.formspring.me/helgam96/q/406136691460425445) uses the form, though my Icelandic is really a bit too rusty to say for sure ;-)

> farð að vinna.
>   Jájá fer að vinna á laugardaginn!

Comment: "Visit", "journey", "go". It might be cognate with the first part of "Ferdinand", but it's not the only possible etymology of that name. (And yeah, I just checked up further on your suggestion).

Comment: I don't speak Icelandic either, but from a bit of Googling, it looks like _farð_ in your sample is a contraction of _farðu_, the imperative form of [_fara_](http://is.wiktionary.org/wiki/fara), "to go". There does, however, exist the (presumably related) noun [_ferð_](http://is.wiktionary.org/wiki/fer%C3%B0) ("trip", "journey"). (Ps. The top search results for either _farð_ or _farðu_ on Google seem to be rather, um, colorful.)

Comment: Could you give a reference for the claim that "Very few languages have th sounds"? Of the 5 I can comment on, only two do not have a _th_ sound. I am referring to 'th' as in _thin_ not _th_ as in _this_.

Comment: @terdon look at http://wals.info chapter 19A, showing less than 10% in a sample of 500+ languages having either sound.

Comment: And that's why one cannot draw robust conclusions from a random sample of five elements. Thank you, I had no idea that phoneme was rare, and thanks for that site, I think I am going to have a lot of fun with it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you were thinking of the [**farthing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farthing_%28British_coin%29)?

Comment: That's exactly what came to mind when I first read the question. As in the poem: *A penny loaf to feed the Pope. / A farthing o' cheese to choke him. / A pint of beer to rinse it down. / A faggot of sticks to burn him.*